# Better Dagger dependency injection based on build type and flavor?

Tags: android, dagger

I am using aproach to provide modules to Dagger described in answer of this question [Android Customize Workflow for Product Flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329584/android-customize-workflow-for-product-flavors)

Our approach is a bit different - we have `Modules` in `debug` build type in `src/debug/java` and in `release` build type in `src/release/java`. Our main module is called `ApplicationModule` it includes all other.

`Modules` in `src/debug/java` provides some custom behaviour for debugging, logging etc and overrides `ApplcationModule`.

Now we have a need to have custom behaviour based on application flavor.

What would be correct approach to do that?

For example flavors A to C should provide custom behaviours, while flavors D to F should provide basic, default behaviour.

So far I came up with such.

- All flavors (not build types) has same class in `src/flavorX/java/com.application.FlavorModule`
- To avoid code duplication only flavors A to C provide custom behavior while other completely empty so that project would compile. And default behaviour is provided my module in `src/main/java`

Is there a better way to achieve such result? Because I don't like empty `src/flavorX/java/com.application.FlavorModule` and don't like code duplication...

Comment: check this project https://github.com/athkalia/Just-Another-Android-App

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Little complicated but here's how I did it:

Create an interface MainComponent and keep it in src/main, this should contain anything that is not flavor specific

```
public interface MainComponent {
    void inject(MyApplication o);

    void inject(BusinessObject o);

    Foo getFoo();

    Activitycomponent plusActivityComponent(ActivityModule activityModule);
```

}

Within each flavor create an interface that inherits from the above one

```
public interface FlavorComponent extends MainComponent {
//flavor specific injection stuff similar to SourceComponent
}
```

Within Debug/Beta/Release create the actual component and extend the FlavorComponent (giving you all the flavor specific niceties).

```
@Singleton
 @Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, FlavorModule.class,
         BetaApplicationModule.class, AnotherModuleJustBecause.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent extends FlavorComponent {
     void inject(NYTApplication a);

 }
```

Notice that you can also include a flavor specific FlavorModule that can be different in each flavor or not include it in Release while including it in Beta.

Also include a ComponentFactory within Debug/Beta/Release returning the common Flavor Component Interface

```
public class ComponentFactory {

public static final FlavorComponent getComponent(Application context) {
        return DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(context))
                .build();
    }
```

and finally from your Application class call:

```
ComponentFactory.getComponent(this).inject(this);
```

The component factory will return the Build Type Component which will extend the Flavor's Component.

Comment: Looking at your `ComponentFactory`, I don't understand why your last line of code isn't `ComponentFactory.getComponent(this).inject(this)`.  Could you explain?

Comment: This might make it more clear by reading the article:  https://medium.com/@theMikhail/flavoring-your-dagger-14ab8bcef9f8

Answer (score 0):

My solution was an adaptation of this [article](https://medium.com/@theMikhail/flavoring-your-dagger-14ab8bcef9f8) cited above

I have an interface call ApplicationComponent in src/main:

```
    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = [

        FlavorModule::class,

        Anyothermoduleyouhave::class

    ])

    interface ApplicationComponent {}
```

Now, inside of each flavor folder, you have to create 2 files:

1. FlavorModule (an abstracted class to call your config)
2. FlavorConfig (the config or whatever specific flavor code you need)

by the way: if you don't have any source folder you can create by adding on your gradle file:

```
        java.srcDirs += ['src/main/kotlin', 'src/myFlavorCode/kotlin']
```

and creating the kotlin folder as well

FlavorModule:

```
    @Module
    class FlavorModule {

        @[Provides Singleton]
        fun getConfig(config: MySpecificFlavor1Config): FlavorConfig

    }
```

FlavorConfig

```
    class MySpecificFlavor1Config @Inject constructor() : FlavorConfig {
        override fun getMyValueThatImLookingFor() = "flavor 1 woooooow"
    }
```

Do the same for the Flavor 2

> Important: to make this work dynamically with dagger, use the same package path for both
> FlavorModule/FlavorConfig classes, like package br.com.main.config, this way dagger understands which FlavorModule to use

Comment: I don't really understand why we need to use `abstract class`,  `abstract fun` and `@[Binds Singleton]` for  the flavor module.
If we can just use `class`, `fun` and `@Provides` respectively