# Injecting a dependency with Dagger 2 only into one of the product flavors

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

My application consists of two product flavors: free and pro. I have an `ApplicationModule` that provides the object for ads, but this object is only required by the free version, as the pro version does not have the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0` dependency. How do I structure my project such that only if the free product flavor is in use the `ApplicationModule` provides the ads object?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have two product flavors, i am assuming the free version classes are in the proper version structure, outside of the 'main' resource set.  and im assuming you have another resource set for paid version.

So, initialize the dagger component inside main source set, but have ApplicationModule reside in each flavors source set.  The module is the provider, so if you want to change the dependencies you'll be able to by defining different providers even though both source sets (paid ,nonpaid) will have the same ApplicationModule in each.

Comment: So inside src, I must have 3 folders: free, pro and main. Did I get that right? My pro version uses a different package name, so do I create separate package folders inside src/pro/ as well?

Comment: Also, what about the `AppNameApplication` class, into which I'm injecting these dependencies. Do I create a different `AppNameApplication` class for each flavor?

Comment: My bad, not `AppNameApplication`. I meant `MainActivity`.

Comment: I would maintain the same package name and structure  for paid and unpaid. This way the main resource can reference them

Comment: If you want your application to have a different Application ID you need to look at manifest place holders for Gradle. As for the mainActivity store in the the main source set

Comment: So if I require a dependency from the ApplicationModule of free flavor, how would I inject it into MainActivty, considering the pro flavor is also using the same MainActivity, but does not require this `Ad` object?

Comment: Probably set a flag in ad object and set it from modules. I might be able to research some more tomorrow.

Comment: Let me know if you arrive at something. I'll continue working on it, and update if I find a way. Thanks!